# How to remove ceiling paint from decorative wood beams

Tags: wood, paint

Wife was painting the ceiling and got ceiling paint on the decorative wood beams (everywhere). I need to remove the paint without damaging the beam. I tried isopropyl alcohol and a scraper because that's all I had but it did not work at all. The paint is Behr Marquee Ceiling Paint.

[image]

Comment: What type of scraper?  Very very careful use of a razor blade scraper for glass/windows might work.

Comment: Or this? [How can I remove old paint from wooden door frames?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33164/how-can-i-remove-old-paint-from-wooden-door-frames)

Comment: Or this? [Removing paint from wood](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36648/removing-paint-from-wood)

Comment: And if those don’t help, paint over it.

Comment: I've found that steam cleaners and credit cards and terry cloth are great for this, at least with the water-based (latex) paint we use.